# python script for limit text file words

Tags: python-2.7

I have an input file like:
input.txt:

```
to
the
cow
eliphant
pigen
then
enthosiastic
```

I want to remove those words which has character length is <= 4 , and if some word has more than 8 character then write those word in new file till 8 character length
output should be like:
output.txt:

```
eliphant
pigen
enthosia
```

This is my code:

```
f2 = open('output.txt', 'w+')
x2 = open('input.txt', 'r').readlines()
for y in x2:
    if (len(y) <= 4):
        y = y.replace(y, '')
        f2.write(y)
    elif (len(y) > 8):
        y = y[0:8]
        f2.write(y)
    else:
        f2.write(y)
f2.close()
print "Done!"
```

when i compile it then it gives the output like:

```
eliphantpigen
then
enthosia
```

it also writes 4 character length word... i don't understand what is the problem and how to write the code to limit character length of text file words....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `with` when working with files, this guarantees that file would be closed.
You have then in your results because your are reading lines and not worlds.
Each line have symbol of ending '\n'. So when you are reading world `then` you have string
'then\n' and `len` of this string is 5.

```
with open('output.txt', 'w+') as ofp, open('input.txt', 'r') as ifp:
    for line in ifp:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) > 8:
            line = line[:8]
        elif len(line) <= 4:
            continue

        ofp.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: check your code and tell me please how to split each word in each line ?

Comment: I guess you are using windows, it uses '\r\n' as line separator. Try change '\n' to '\r\n'.

Comment: your edit have issue when length of string is more then 4 and less then 8.

Comment: now check the code... again edit it... and now its working fine... thanks sir